# Checked Combobox inside DataTemplate which is inside Listbox DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datatemplate

I have a listbox and its data template. But in its DataTemplate i have CheckedCombobox DataTemplate. Wanted to know how to set the bindings. I have tried below things to get which are items checked in child element by each listbox item. Below is the code which is not working.

```
<ListBox 
    Name="ListLayers" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding LstDragList}" 
    Height="123" 
    Width="283"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox 
                    Name="childlayers" 
                    Style="{StaticResource EditableCboStyle}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding lstLayerModel}"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedLayers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboboxItemContainerStyle}" 
                    Width="200" 
                    IsEditable="True" 
                    IsReadOnly="False"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ComboBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                    >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Model}">
                            <CheckBox 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                Content="{Binding DisplayLayer}"
                                />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Models:

```
public class DragList : ObservableObject
{
    public DragList()
    {
        _selectedLayers = string.Empty;
    }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> lstLayerModel { get; set; }
    public string  Text { get; set; }

    private string _selectedLayers;

    public string SelectedLayers
    {
        get { return _selectedLayers; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref _selectedLayers, value, () => this.SelectedLayers); }
    }

    private int _selectedLayerInx;

    public int SelectedLayerInx
    {
        get { return _selectedLayerInx; }
        set { SetAndNotify(ref _selectedLayerInx, value, () => this.SelectedLayerInx); }
    }

}
```

my constructor viewmodel:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _lstLayers = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    mCheckedItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    _tempDragList = new List<DragList>();

    _lstLayers.CollectionChanged += _lstLayers_CollectionChanged;
    _lstLayers.Add(new Model
    {
        LayerName = "All",
        LayerNumber = "",

        IsChecked = true
    });
    _lstLayers.Add(new Model { LayerName = "Layer one", LayerNumber = "1", IsChecked = false });
    _lstLayers.Add(new Model { LayerName = "Layer two", LayerNumber = "2", IsChecked = false });
    _lstLayers.Add(new Model { LayerName = "Layer three", LayerNumber = "3", IsChecked = false });

    _lstDragList = new List<DragList>();
    _lstDragList.Add(new DragList { FileName = "Test", lstLayerModel = _lstLayers });
    _lstDragList.Add(new DragList { FileName = "Test1", lstLayerModel = _lstLayers });

    _tempDragList = _lstDragList;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what isn't working? Is LstDragList actually the name of the public property in the viewmodel?

Comment: Does Model have the properties you're trying to bind to?

Comment: Use Snoop to examine the bindings (and the related DataContexts) at runtime.

Comment: I have one list<Model> and inside this Model i have List<ChildModel> that is mentioned above. IsChecked property of the combobox is bound with the List<ChildModel> in runtime we have more items of List<Model> but when i check first combobox of checked item it also reflects the same to second item of combobox checked property. Normally datatemplate bound should bound with List<childmodel>.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to use [RelativeSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) on the inner bindings to get the correct DataContext like so:

```
{Binding DataContext.SelectedRow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

There are many other articles on RelativeSource here on SO that should provide you with that you need.